# Grails: data source url showing blank while accessing from custom script

Tags: grails

I have a custom script created using grails and i tried to access the datasource **url** defined in **datasource.groovy** by the following way.

```
// my custom script file
    includeTargets << grailsScript('_GrailsPackage')
    target(main: "Your main") {
        depends(compile,createConfig)
        println "My value: ${config.dataSource.url}"
    }
```

but the output is showing like this.

> My value: [:]

If i print the `config.dataSource.username` or `config.dataSource.password` it is showing the correct value.

The **url** value defined in my DataSource.groovy as like as the username and password how defined.

```
production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.40.67:3306/ifpqa?autoReconnect=true"
            username = "root"
            password = "root"           
        }
    }
```

Please help me to find a solution for this.

Comment: try adding `println "Environment = ${Environment.current} (${Environment.current.name})"`  Does that tell you production ?

Comment: Try this `import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder` `def _url      = ConfigurationHolder.config.dataSource.url`

Comment: `${Environment.current}` cannot be accessed from a gant script but `${grailsSettings.grailsEnv}` showing that is **production**

Comment: @AbhilashShajan `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder` also cannot be accessed from a gant script